# Android make periodic tasks into services

Tags: android, service

I am trying to background my activity. As I understand it, the best approach is to use services. I want to keep the following two tasks always running:

1. The first task is always launched. It is run periodically on 1 hour intervals.
2. The second task may or may not be running. This runs periodically every 1 minute. It depends on whether the user turns this part on or not.

I want both of these tasks to always be running and I am confused how I make them into services.

Should I be creating two services for each of these tasks, and the services call the associated method in the activity? And I simply start/stop the services to start/stop the tasks? If so, how should this be done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the following classes:

- [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
- [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Create inexact alarms for the intervals you want. When the alarm triggers, it will fire off a PendingIntent - use [`PendingIntent.getService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to create the PendingIntents.

This approach is preferred because (a) `IntentService` automatically stops itself when it finishes its task, so you don't have services running when you don't actually need them to be running; (b) `IntentService` uses a background thread to do its processing, so it will never be using the UI thread if your app is in the foreground at that moment; and (c) using an inexact alarm allows the OS to coordinate multiple alarms to fire at once, minimizing device wakes, which is better for battery.